# Select whole column by clicking ColumnHeader. WPF DATAGRID

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a data grid which has disabled sorting. What I want to achieve is - by clicking a column header I want to select all cells in this column(select whole column). I've added `EventSetter` to my `DataGridColumnHeader` to bind some method to `Click` event, but I have no idea how this method should be written. Any ideas?

**My code:**

```
private void columnHeaderClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var columnHeader = sender as DataGridColumnHeader;
        if (columnHeader != null)
        {
            if (dgDane.SelectedCells != null)
            {
                dgDane.SelectedCells.Clear();
            }
            foreach (var item in dgDane.Items)
            {
                dgDane.SelectedCells.Add(new DataGridCellInfo(item, columnHeader.Column));                  
            }
            dgDane.Focus();
        }
    }
```

I Edited the code, this one above works fine(thanks to @nit). I've added focus to `DataGrid` because it was necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
private void columnHeaderClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var columnHeader = sender as DataGridColumnHeader;
        if (columnHeader != null)
        {
            dataGrid.SelectedCells.Clear();
            foreach (var item in dataGrid.Items)
            {
                dataGrid.SelectedCells.Add(new DataGridCellInfo(item,columnHeader.Column));
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure you set `SelectionUnit="Cell"` on `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            SelectionUnit="Cell" />
```

Comment: Well, it's close but, If i click on column header - it selects the column but its 'inactive select' and if i clicked in some column second time it returns exception "The collection already contains an item". It works fine only when i click some cell and then i click column header(another then the column of selected cell) but then i want to select only the column which i clicked i dont want this 'extra' 1 cell selected.

Comment: So i guess .Clear() is not enough :(

Comment: Nope, it works :) i was just clearing the wrong collection i wrote SelectedItems instead of SelectedCells. Thanks for help ! Marked as answer :)